# My code just works if I am on Debug mode but not at run time, why?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to export the Excel range as a picture so, I am using the below code

```
Set Sheet = Worksheets("Test")

zoom_coef = 100 / Sheet.Parent.Windows(1).Zoom
Set area = Sheet.Range(Sheet.PageSetup.PrintArea)
area.CopyPicture xlPrinter
Set chartobj = Sheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, area.Width * zoom_coef, area.Height * zoom_coef)
Sheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate
chartobj.Chart.Paste
chartobj.Chart.Export "C:\Test.png", "png"
chartobj.Delete
```

This works fine when I debug, however when I run it, the image is  not pasted into Chart and I get a blank White images

I already tried putting Application.Wait, Loop but no luck
Can someone help me please

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me quite ok.
What is your `Sheet.PageSetup.PrintArea`? I have replaced it by a hard-coded range.

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim SHeet As Worksheet
    Set SHeet = Worksheets(1)        
    zoom_coef = 100 / SHeet.Parent.Windows(1).Zoom
    Set area = SHeet.Range("A1:A6")
    area.CopyPicture xlPrinter
    Set chartobj = SHeet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, area.Width * zoom_coef, area.Height * zoom_coef)
    SHeet.ChartObjects(1).Activate
    chartobj.Chart.Paste
    chartobj.Chart.Export "C:\path\file.png", "png"
    chartobj.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: the range is A1:G20 and i am using Excel 2016 64Bit

Comment: @SamK - and it does not work? I have tried it on 32Bit, it worked.